# Mercurial error on Aptana Studio 3 Startup

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, aptana3

I installed Mylyn and Egit  packages in Aptana Studio 3.0.8 and am trying to work with my git repositories.  What is strange is that I am getting an error message when I switch workspaces or startup Aptana:

MercurialEclipse plugin:

> There are some unexpected Mercurial errors occured.  Please check the
>   Error Log view for detailed information. Process start failed: hg -y
>   debuginstall Cannot run program "hg": error=2, No such file or
>   directory Process start failed: hg -y debuginstall Cannot run program
>   "hg": error=2, No such file or directory Process start failed: hg -y
>   debuginstall Cannot run program "hg": error=2, No such file or
>   directory

This shows up in the Team preferences.   Is there some plugin that I should disable?  I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got hg installed? On ubuntu you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```